# How can I see concise list of all Facebook events that I attend or am "Interested in"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Few weeks ago I've seen a Facebook event advertising exhibition that I'm interested in. I marked it "I'm interested".

Later I wanted to find the event. I knew that it's coming in a few days. I went to the events tab on Facebook and expected to find it there. Instead I found bunch of other unrelated events that I didn't mark as interesting.

So if the events I like are not under the events tab, where they are.

Note that I did find the event eventually by first googling it out of facebook, then typing the keywords in facebook search. It did exist, it is marked as interesting and starts at sunday.